# angular js 1.x orderBy is taking 99 as biggest number even though more than 400 records

Tags: angularjs

```
 <tr ng-repeat="item in (filteredItems = (expenseArray |  orderBy:'-expense_id')) track by $index"><td>{{item.expense_id}}</td></tr>
```

result is like below

Total Number of records is 416, Biggest Expesnse Id and latest Expense Id is 416

by using orderBy '-expense_id' in ng-repeat ,
We are getting result  as latest record   with expesnse_id  99,98,97....43,42,416,415,414....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. In response the `expense_id` should be of type number.

Adding JavaScript example on how it.

> The default sort order is according to string Unicode code points.

You may use compare Function as given  in the mozilla developer network ([reference link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)).

```css
var arr1=[99,98,97 ,43,42,416,415,414];
var arr2=[99,98,97 ,43,42,416,415,414];


//-----------YOUR SCENARIO------------- 

function myFunction2() {
  arr1.sort();
  console.log(arr1);
}

myFunction2();

//Expected o/p : [414, 415, 416, 42, 43, 97, 98, 99]


//-----------EXPECTED SCENARIO------------- 

function myFunction() {
  arr2.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a - b
  }
  );
  console.log(arr2);
}
//Expected o/p : [42, 43, 97, 98, 99, 414, 415, 416]

myFunction();
```

For angular you need to pass a function in similar function(expression) in orderBy.

```
 <tr ng-repeat="item in (filteredItems = (expenseArray |  orderBy:'yourFunction')) track by $index"><td>{{item.expense_id}}</td></tr>
```

```js
$scope.yourFunc = function(item){
    return parseInt(item.expense_id);
};
```

**Reference Link**

1. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort
2. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy

> Serious developers in other languages expect to put in the effort to learn most or all of the
>   language(s) they primarily write in, but JS developers seem to stand out from the crowd in
>   the sense of typically not learning very much of the language : **YDKJS**

This is why at first vanilla JavaScript example was added.

Comment: well explained.